# How to tell if an object implements a method like toString()?

Tags: java, reflection

I am writing a testing library and I want to be able to handle objects that may not have been provided their own implementation of `String toString()`.

In those cases, rather that using the useless default implementation, I'd like to use the [Apache Commons-Lang `ToStringBuilder`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ToStringBuilder.html) instead... but would rather use an object's implementation of `toString()` if available.

How can I tell if an object has an implementation of `toString()` other than the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I have found is by using [`java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethod(String,Class<?>...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class...-) and calling it on the object's class hierarchy like so:

```
public static boolean objectHasToStringImplemented( final Object o ){
    return classHasToStringImplemented( o.getClass() );
}


public static boolean classHasToStringImplemented( final Class<?> initialClass ){

    Class<?> classToCheck = initialClass;
    while( classToCheck != Object.class ){
        if(  classImplementsToString( classToCheck )  ){
            return true;
        }

        classToCheck = classToCheck.getSuperclass();
    }

    return false;
}


private boolean classImplementsToString( final Class<?> aClass ){
    try{
        aClass.getDeclaredMethod( "toString" );
        return true;

    }catch( NoSuchMethodException e ){
        return false;

    }
}
```

and then I sped it up by caching answers and not triggering exceptions

```
//NB: implementation is synchronized and thus thread-safe
private static final Hashtable<Class<?>,Boolean> cachedAnswers = new Hashtable<>();
static {
    cachedAnswers.put( Object.class, Boolean.FALSE );
}

public static Boolean objectHasToStringImplemented( final Object o ){
    return classHasToStringImplemented( o.getClass() );
}


public static Boolean classHasToStringImplemented( final Class<?> classToCheck ){
    if( cachedAnswers.containsKey( classToCheck )  ){
        return cachedAnswers.get( classToCheck );
    }

    final Boolean result = classImplementsToString( classToCheck )  ||  classHasToStringImplemented( classToCheck.getSuperclass() );
    cachedAnswers.put( classToCheck, result );

    return result;
}

private static Boolean classImplementsToString( final Class<?> aClass ){
    for( Method m : aClass.getDeclaredMethods() ){
        if(  isToString( m )  ){
            return Boolean.TRUE;
        }
    }

    return Boolean.FALSE;
}


private static Boolean isToString( final Method m ){
    if(  m.getParameterCount() == 0  && m.getName().equals( "toString" )  &&  m.getReturnType().equals( String.class )  ){
        return Boolean.TRUE;

    }else{
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    }
}
```

I have tested this with:

- [`java.lang.StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (which implements `toString()`)
- [`java.util.ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) (which inherits an implementation from [`java.util.AbstractList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/AbstractCollection.html))

  - [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) (which only  has a static `toString(java.lang.Object)`)
  - and a custom class which only had a `String toString(int i)` method defined

---

**NB:** I have not tested this with `default` method implementation since I do not currently have access to the Java 8 JRE.